# Running cron job at reboot

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I'm having problem with running cron job at reboot.
Anyway here's what i write in when i run crontab -e:

```
@reboot python /home/user/script.py
```

It doesn't work(it should update .json file with new content). Any solutions?
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 if that is any help, i tried to edit python with usr/bin/python but with no luck.

Script.py is file which consist of these modules:

```
import json
import urllib
import mechanize,cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Does the script run successfully if you do `python /home/user/script.py`?

Comment: Have you [checked for cron errors](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged)?

Comment: Try somethng like `@reboot python /home/user/script.py > /Path/ToLog/log 2>&1` and check logs.

Comment: You can check the [Debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) section in the [crontab]  tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can add time delay @reboot sleep 60 python /home/user/script.py . If it did not work then add in your script at first line #!/usr/bin/python 
To check for errors go to /var/spool/yourUserName